# React in an existing managment project

Tags: reactjs

I m  having some trouble with  a project. I'm working on, is  a management project and I want to add some page made with react . ( now the project is made with js + dojo and php ) .
Nutshel I want to make a react project with many component( every component is a different page ) that I can call back in some page of an existing managment project. Obviously i dont have to download react libraries everytime I open a react page. How could I do it?

Comment: Your issue is very unclear.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you mean by calling back a react page in an existing management project, but this is where you should be starting if you want to incorperate react in an already made project: [Add React To A Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) (React Docs)

Comment: I ve red it , but how can I add some npm package ( like antd ) ?